# Python 3 определение и обработка полученного текста

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Не могу придумать как правильно сделать получение даты в тексте и обработка его.
Суть в следующем. Пользователь пишет текстом, к примеру, "report 20.07.2017" и я дальше уже хочу с него выбирать только дату и использовать её.
Но не могу понять как из message.text == 'report' сделать что-то типа message.text == 'report 20.07.2017', но при этом дата будет разная.

```
    elif message.text == 'report':
    report = subprocess.check_output('aws s3 ls s3://mystorage/test_folder/' + date_now + '/', shell=True)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, report)
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

а вы пробовали так?

```
elif message.text.find('report') != -1 and len(message.text) == 17:
    list = message.text.split()
    date = list[1]  
    report = subprocess.check_output('aws s3 ls s3://mystorage/test_folder/' + date + '/', shell=True)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, report)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Очень помогли!

Answer (score 0):

Способов множество (как это часто бывает).

К сожалению я не знаком конкретно с Python, так что дам советы в общем.
Самый простой это проверить наличие подстроки в `message.text`.
Можно строку разбить по пробелу и проверять первую часть на `'report'`, вторая тогда как раз таки будет содержать дату.

Answer (score 0):

Способов действительно много... Первое что приходит:

```
if 'report' in message.text:
    report_list = message.text.split()
    print(report_list)      # получится список
```

Можно использовать регулярные выражения - для этого читать про модуль re